# How to access a server system's local db from another system?(case:server-client scenario)

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2014-express

we used this connection string in client system where "Data Source=**.***.**.57" is of server ip address and made the changes in the sql server configuration manager in server system accordingly.(i.e: TCP/IP protocol enabled)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConString"
         connectionString="Data Source=**<ip address>,1433\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HYD_TM;User ID=**;Password=**;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: And the error(s) you got would be what???

Answer (score 0):

Its always easier to debug connection string problems from an interface that is interactive such as Excel or sql management studio.  In excel you can try to import a table from the data tab.  If you succeed you can inspect the connection string and use it in your app.